# AWS Codepipeline first stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, devops, pipeline, aws-codepipeline

I've created a pipeline using codecommit->codebuild->codepipeline in order to build and test automatically my android app located on my github repository.

But at first stage after build step the pipeline returns this error:

[image]

I don't know the app location if it refers to .apk file because there is no .apk file into my repository.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi @rubik90, you created a pipeline run that consists of: a source stage (codecommit) then a build stage (codebuild) and then another stage (which is the one failing). Is that correct? what's in that failing action? is that a custom script?

Comment: Hi @marianogg9 I followed slavishly this aws tutorial 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-codebuild-devicefarm.html

You're right, the source stage is handled by codecommit (source github) and the build stage by codebuild. My problem is buildspec.yml. I notice that the next test stage needs a file (I think zip or apk file) but I am not able to check if the build step creates this file properly. 

I do believe that the last line of buildspec file is what I'm doing wrong, but can't find the solution on the web. Have you ever faced a similar job? Thank you.

Comment: This is the buildspec file I'm using

version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - java -version
      - bash ./gradlew assembleDebug
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
      - '**/*'

Comment: CodePipeline works with artifacts in zip format, have you tried zipping the apk file in the post_build step (within buildspec) and then add the path of that zip file to `artifacts` clause? it might be possible that apk file is not being left in a visible path by the build process: trust me, i've been there. A quick check would be adding a `ls -ltr` execution in the `post_build` clause so that you can see if the apk is actually in there. Hope that helps!

Comment: the point is that running ls -ltr i can see no apk file, so i think that I'm wrong in buildspec setting, even if it's very trivial as you can see in my above reply. Very confused. further the app works properly on me phone so that it's to be excluded that I made coding errors.
if I don't have an apk file as output how is it possible that the build phase is successful?

Comment: If you cannot see any apk file, then there's something missing or the apk is being left elsewhere. Maybe you can run a `find . -name *.apk` to look for it recursively in current path. The build stage can finish successfully because there're no errors, as in command or execution or runtime errors; this seems a bit more functional, the apk target file is not being created in an expected path rather than the build process not creating it at all. The apk file is not an output per se, it's an artifact you refer to in `artifacts` section even though there could be nothing in there.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I followed your hint and this came up:

[Container] 2020/02/11 10:01:16 Running command find . -name *.apk
./app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk;

so I write this path in the artifact line into buildspec file but the test stage still isn't able to find it because returns me the same error:

Did not find the file app-release-unsigned.apk in the input artifacts ZIP file. Verify the file is stored in your pipeline's Amazon S3 artifact bucket;

even if I inserted app-release-unsigned.apk into "app -optional" field.

Comment: Can you check if that apk file is actually in the zip file (input artifact) within S3 bucket please? you can access it via UI in S3 and download its content. Also, check this `discard-paths` option in buildspec ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an apk file in your input artifact to the 'Test' stage (AWS Device Farm action) and then specify the apk filename in 'App - optional' field while setting up the AWS Device Farm Test action in CodePipeline.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have specifed the name "app-release.apk" in the 'App -optional fields' and the test stage fails with the following error:

Did not find the file app-release.apk in the input artifacts ZIP file. Verify the file is stored in your pipeline's Amazon S3 artifact bucket: codepipeline-us-west-2-416983371916 key: is2_pipeline/BuildArtif/EYqfnM3

I'm not sure the build stage creates the zip file properly with the apk inside. How can I check the presence of my .apk file?